# Which word should I look up to find definitions for 「はけた」?

Tags: words

From Bocchi The Rock! ep7.

> （虹夏）昨日のライブは
> あたしの友達が
> 結構 来てくれたから
> チケット はけたんだけど…

Which word should I look up to find definitions for 「はけた」? The word was written in hiragana so it's hard to be sure sometimes.

I found 捌ける with the definition 「商品などが、よく売れていく。さばける。」 but I'm not sure if it's the right one.

Comment: Yes. That is [捌ける](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E6%8D%8C%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B/#je-60381) + た, meaning *sold well*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's the right definition. 捌ける【はける】 is an intransitive verb that basically means 出て行く, but for some reason, it is used exclusively in contexts such as the drainage of land, the exit of audiences, the removal of stage equipment, and the emptying the stock of goods (including tickets).

> ###### [捌ける](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%8D%8C%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B-1)
>
> 1. to drain; to flow (unobstructed); to run off​
> 2. to sell well; to be in good demand​
> 3. to exit the stage; to remove (a prop) from the stage